# How to create a function that adds different categories to a table with tidyverse in R

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I am creating lots of tibbles. Yet, because this is repeatable I am trying to create a function that eases my work. It is necessary to create this function with tidyverse library in R. This is the created function:

```
cfg_write <- function(given = c(1:2), 
                              common = c(1:2), 
                              table = name_of_a_table, 
                              path = "path/to/save"){

        table <- tibble::tibble(given = c(1:2),
                                common = c(1:2))
        table 

        saveRDS(table, file = path)

    }
```

To bear in mind, in given and common parameters in the function I want to pass more than 2 strings, sometimes I can reach 18 levels rather than 2 as it is set in the "given" and "common".

Two things I do not get with the function created:

1. I wish I will get extra rows when I pass in the given and common parameters. These are categories of given variable.
2. And secondly, when I attempt to create several tibbles I get a tibble with two columns, which is good, and each column has a number, 1 and 2 which isn't what I expect.

This is what I do, to be more specific:

```
test <- cfg_write(given = c('Adrian', "Mary", "Neil"), 
                   common = c("name1", "name2", "name3"), 
                   table = test, path = "/users/bg/test.rds")
```

However, I get this:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(given = 1:2, common = 1:2), row.names = c(NA,-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not passed the argument names into the function body. As you have not used these arguments in the function body any new arguments supplied when using the function will be ignored. The table argument is also obsolete as the name of the tibble will be whatever you assign the function call to, in this case `test`.   Perhaps this will move things in the right direction? **Note I have changed the file path**

```
cfg_write <- function(given = c(1:2), 
                              common = c(1:2),
                              path = "path/to/save"){

        table <- tibble::tibble(given = given,
                                common = common)

        saveRDS(table, file = path)

    }

test <- cfg_write(given = c('Adrian', "Mary", "Neil"), 
                  common = c("name1", "name2", "name3"), 
                  table = test, path = "Desktop/test.rds")
readRDS("Desktop/test.rds")

  provided standard
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 Adrian   name1   
2 Mary     name2   
3 Neil     name3
```